# Python Multiprocessing - Process Termination (cannot start a process twice)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Can anyone tell me why the following code gives the error "cannot start a process twice"?  By my reckoning, p1 and p2 should already have been force-closed by the p.terminate() command

EDIT: Have added in some more code to give context - wanted to come up with a simple example but left out the while loops

```
import time
import os
from multiprocessing import Process
import datetime

def a():
    print ("a starting")
    time.sleep(30)
    print ("a ending")

def b():
    print ("b starting")
    time.sleep(30)
    print ("b ending")

morning = list(range(7,10))
lunch = list(range(11,14))
evening = list(range(17,21))
active = morning + lunch + evening

if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = Process(target = a)
    p2 = Process(target = b)
    while True:
        while (datetime.datetime.now().time().hour) in active:
            p1.start()
            p2.start() 
            time.sleep(5)
            p1.terminate()
            p2.terminate()
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            print ("Outside hours, waiting 30 mins before retry")
            time.sleep(1800)
```

Comment: why two `p1.start()` and `p2.start()`?

Comment: Oh, sorry! There's a while loop encapsulating this to run the code over and over at certain times of day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says you cannot start a process twice. That is exactly what you're doing when you call `p1.start()` and `p2.start()` again after the terminates. Try recreating them like you did at the beginning.

```
p1.terminate()
p2.terminate()
time.sleep(5)
p1 = Process(target = a)
p2 = Process(target = b)
p1.start()
p2.start()
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't realise that you had to keep redefining the processes.  I interpreted the error "you cannot start a process twice" as "you cannot re-run a process that is already running" so thought there was an error with terminate(). Doesn't seem logical to me to have to keep redefining processes over and over though

Comment: 4 years later and this helped me out, thanks!